# How to prove the Frechet–Nikodym metric is complete?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the book Measure Theory Vol I, (V.I. Bogachev), Bottom line 10 of Page 54, how to get the inequality $\cdots\leq \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}2^{-k}$ ?

How to prove the Frechet–Nikodym metric is complete?

Comment: Could you add a link or the necessary context?

Comment: can download from http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/f/20239526.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have read it recently, and I think the derivation is not correct here. The result should be derived as follows: Note that
\begin{align}
  \bigcup_{k=m}^\infty{A_k\setminus A_m}&=\bigcup_{k=m}^\infty{(A_k\setminus A_m)}\\
  &=(A_{m+1}\setminus A_m)\cup(A_{m+2}\setminus A_m)\cup(A_{m+3}\setminus A_m)\cup\dots\\
  &=(A_{m+1}\setminus A_m)\cup(A_{m+2}\setminus (A_m\cup A_{m+1}))\cup(A_{m+3}\setminus (A_m\cup A_{m+1}\cup A_{m+2}))\cup\dots\\
  &\subset(A_{m+1}\setminus A_m)\cup(A_{m+2}\setminus A_{m+1})\cup(A_{m+3}\setminus A_{m+2})\cup\dots\\
  &=\bigcup_{k=m}^\infty{(A_{k+1}\setminus A_k)}.
\end{align}
Therefore, according to subadditivity of measure, we have
\begin{align}
  \mu(\bigcup_{k=m}^\infty{A_k}\setminus A_m)\leq\sum_{k=m}^\infty{\mu(A_{k+1}\setminus A_k)}\leq\sum_{k=m}^\infty{\mu(A_k\Delta A_{k+1})}<\sum_{k=m}^\infty{2^{-k}}.
\end{align}
The result follows.