# Completeness of Nikodym Metric

Tags: measure-theory

It is required to prove the completeness of Nikodym Metric Space, but I stucked in a condition:

Let $(X, S)$ a measurable space with $\mu$ a measure over $S$. Let

$$F = \{A \in S: \mu(A) < + \infty\}$$

Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation given by $A \sim B \Longleftrightarrow \mu(A \Delta B) = 0$. Let $\bar{F} = F/_{\sim}$ and $d([A], [B]) = \mu(A \Delta B)$.

It is required to prove that $(\bar{F}, d)$ is a complete metric space.

So, for $([A_n]) \subseteq \bar{F}$ a Cauchy sequence, there is a subsequence $([A_{n_k}]) \subseteq ([A_n])$ such that
$$d([A_{n_k}],[A_{n_{k+1}}]) = \mu(A_{n_k} \Delta A_{n_{k+1}}) < \frac{1}{2^k}$$

I already showed that $d([A_{n_k}], [A_*]) \to 0$, but I cannot understand why

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \inf A_{n_k} = A_* \in F$$

that is, to show that $\mu(A_*) < + \infty$.

I would appreciate help to understand why $A_*$ has finite measure.

[How to prove the Frechet–Nikodym metric is complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489405/how-to-prove-the-frechet-nikodym-metric-is-complete)

[Proving completeness of Nikodym Metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527881/proving-completeness-of-nikodym-metric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A_\ast:=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{j\ge k}A_{n_j}$$Observe that $\mu(\cap_{j\ge n}A_{n_j})\le\mu(A_{n_k})$. It's sufficient to show $\mu(\cup_{k\in\Bbb N}A_{n_k})<\infty$. It's well known that that's just $\lim_{N\to\infty}\mu(\cup_{k=1}^NA_{n_k})$.

We have for $N\in\Bbb N$: $$\bigcup_{k=1}^{N+1}A_{n_k}\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^NA_{n_k}=A_{n_{N+1}}\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^NA_{n_k}=\bigcap_{k=1}^NA_{n_{N+1}}\setminus A_{n_k}\subseteq A_{n_{N+1}}\setminus A_{n_N}\subseteq A_{n_{N+1}}\Delta A_{n_N}$$Therefore: $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^NA_{n_k}\right)\le A_{n_1}+\sum_{j=1}^N2^{-j}$$Follows by induction and one observes that $\mu(A_\ast)$ is finite.

Comment: Why the string of equalities and contentions implies that the last measure of the union is bounded? I'm mean, where should $\bigcup_{k = 1}^{N} A_{n_k}$ be contained?

Comment: @BlueTomato $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^NA_{n_k}\right)\le\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{N-1}A_{n_k}\right)+\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^NA_{n_k}\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^{N-1}A_{n_k}\right)$$Induct on this

Comment: Now I got the whole point. You are observing the that the measure is bounded recursively. Thanks so much sir!